# mySQL showing null in images field

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

when I try to insert an image in MySQL database it shows:

> Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

but when I try to view it in net beans it tells that the field is null.
Also in MySQL when I put the query to display the field it shows null under the image column.

The strangest thing is that it happens only for some images and other images get added to the database and are displayed by the java net beans.

The table creation query  is:

```
create table rto(sno int(2), image longblob);
```

the query to insert image in table is:

```
insert into rto values(2, LOAD_FILE('I:\WP_20150925_004.jpg'));
```

The java code is:

```
JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
                       chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                       File f=chooser.getSelectedFile();
                       String filename=f.getAbsolutePath();
                       System.out.println(filename);
        {
 try{   int r= Integer.parseInt(jt2.getText());
               Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/darshanproject","root","");
               Statement st = con.createStatement();
               String q = "Insert into rto values("+r+",LOAD_FILE('"+filename+"'));" ;
                int rs = st.executeUpdate(q);
if (rs>0)
    System.out.println("image inserted");
else
    System.out.println("not inserted");
           }catch(Exception ex){
               System.out.println(ex);
           }
        }
 // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You should post the java code, the image is either inserted (seems to be the case) or not (unless it's a cat pic :p)

Comment: I have updated the java code

Comment: I think you can find the solution in here
[Saving An Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035883/saving-an-image-in-mysql-from-java)

Comment: didn't found any solution there.

Comment: filename = filename.replace("\\","/");