# How to retrieve image file from database using java

Tags: java

I can store image file to database but how can I get the image as a file and preview using java , it's like quikr image uploading

Comment: What have you tried? What are you getting? How is the image saved in the DB, as base 64?

Comment: Image saves as binary, can i convert it as image file

Answer (score 2):

Following code will store and retrieve images to MySql DB.

Store image into DB

```
 public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
    // DB connection
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/your db name","root","root");

        File file=new File("E:\\sample_image.png");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);

    //Insert image into db
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into image_table (name,image) values(?,?)"); 
        ps.setString(1,"image 1");
        ps.setBinaryStream(2,fis,(int)file.length());
        ps.executeUpdate();

        ps.close();
        fis.close();
        con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Retrieve image into DB

Below code will retrieve image from database and save it @ location "E:\sample_image.png".

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
    // DB connection
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/your db name","root","root");

        File file=new File("E:\\sample_image.png");
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte b[];
        Blob blob;

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from image_table"); 
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            blob=rs.getBlob("image");
            b=blob.getBytes(1,(int)blob.length());
            fos.write(b);
        }

        ps.close();
        fis.close();
        con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's web app ,i don't want save in local memory, i want to restore the byte and convert it to image file. But not save in local memory

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `Image` to `Bytes`, save to db or restore from db in bytes

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java) to convert to bytes
or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035883/saving-an-image-in-mysql-from-java) which is like your problem

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580038/byte-array-to-image-file) for byte to image operations

Comment: How to convert bytes to image and preview?